# How express this code more succinctly in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

Inside an each loop, I would like to output an HTML element if it's the beginning of the loop, or the index is a multiple of five.

```
- images.each do |image, index|
  - if index == 1 || index == 5 || index == 10 || index == 15 # this is not scalable!
    .row-fluid
  .span2
    div.image-wrapper
      = image_tag image.url
```

Is there a better way to express this in Ruby?

I want to output a maximum of 5 `span2` divs inside a `row-fluid` div.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Meet [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

```
if index % 5 == 0
```

> Basically, I want to make sure you only output a maximum of 5 span2 divs inside a row-fluid div.

Well, that's another story completely

```
- images.each_slice(5) do |slice|
  .row-fluid
  - slice.each do |image|
    .span2
      div.image-wrapper
        = image_tag image.url
```

Documentation on [Enumerable#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice).

Comment: you can also use `1.modulo 5`

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you. I I'm glad you cleared that up. `each_with_index` does not work for my requirement. I'll accept this when I can.